# how to initialize the vector with class pointer(STL)

Tags: c++, vector, stl

just want to know to initialize the vector with class pointe

```
# include <animation> // a class
std::vector<animation*> animlist;
animlist = new std::vector<animtion*>();
```

but it shows error "error C2678"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your vector is not a pointer, and it is already initialized here:

```
std::vector<animation*> animlist; // size 0 vector of animation pointers
```

What you do in the next line is to attempt to *assign* a pointer to an `std::vector<animaiton*>` to `animlist`. This doesn't work because a vector does not have an assignment operator that takes a pointer to a vector of the same type.

Comment: thanks, but stil i can't able to push item to it? animlist.push_back(anim)//anim object of animation class

Comment: @juanchopanza: s/pointers to `animlist`/pointers to `animation`/

Comment: @sank:  Not surprising.  An `animation` and a pointer to one, are different types.  `animlist.push_back(&anim);` would probably work (`&` being the "address-of" operator, which would return you a pointer), though it almost certainly wouldn't do what you want in the long run.  It's starting to sound like you need to drill in the difference between objects and pointers to objects.

Comment: thanks @cHao, i'm just staring with c++, so still long ways to go, this is what i try to do void                      Sprite::addAnimation(const Animation& anim)
{
 animList.push_back(anim);
}

Comment: @sank: What's more likely, then, is that you want a `std::vector<animation>`.  Don't just go messing with pointers for the heck of it.  :)  `std::vector` will do the right thing as long as your `animation` class knows how to copy itself...which is another of those basic things that beginning C++ programmers get drilled in early.

Comment: @sank what cHao said: read up on the difference between pointers and objects.

Answer (score 0):

you don't initialize a vector. vector is a container. it's good to go when you declare it. you initialize an object, and push it to the container.